# SQL query to calculate % of time in month columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I am trying to calculate the percentage of time a person has been on a team month over month.

How do you calculate columns for Jan-19, Feb-19, Mar-19, etc to show what percentage of time each person was on the team based on their start and end dates?

Right now i have this data:

```
Team Name   Res_Name         Res_Start_Date   Res_End_Date
Swoosh      Bob Jones         1/1/2019  
Swoosh      Mary Johnson      5/5/2019  
Marvel      Bill Bobberson    10/29/2019      12/31/2019
Marvel      David James       4/4/2019        4/28/2019
Marvel      John Smith        5/1/2019        10/1/2019
```

I want the new columns structured like this:
[Column format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEJ7u.png)

```
Team Name   Res_Name         Res_Start_Date   Res_End_Date   Jan-19     Feb-19      Mar-19  etc..

Swoosh      Bob Jones         1/1/2019  
Swoosh      Mary Johnson      5/5/2019  
Marvel      Bill Bobberson    10/29/2019      12/31/2019
Marvel      David James       4/4/2019        4/28/2019
Marvel      John Smith        5/1/2019        10/1/2019
```

And expect that the out put of the calculated columns for this data would be:
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm42Y.png)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please also care to explain the logic of your %age calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that comes close to what you expect.

With the difference that the year isn't in the column names.

This way, the same query doesn't have to be modified next year.

How it works?

First the start & end dates of the months are generated in a CTE.

Those are then joined to the table on the ranges.
To calculate a percent per month for each resource.

And that result is then pivoted.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE YourTable 
> (
>   Team_Name varchar2(30),
>   Res_Name varchar2(30),
>   Res_Start_Date date,
>   Res_End_Date date
> );
>
> INSERT INTO YourTable (Team_Name, Res_Name, Res_Start_Date, Res_End_Date)
>       SELECT 'Swoosh', 'Bob Jones', '1-JAN-2019', null FROM DUAL
> UNION SELECT 'Swoosh', 'Mary Johnson', '5-MAY-2019', null FROM DUAL
> UNION SELECT 'Marvel', 'Bill Bobberson', '29-OCT-2019', '31-DEC-2019' FROM DUAL
> UNION SELECT 'Marvel', 'David James', '4-APR-2019', '28-APR-2019' FROM DUAL
> UNION SELECT 'Marvel', 'John Smith', '1-MAY-2019', '1-OCT-2019' FROM DUAL
> ```

> ```
> WITH MONTHS AS
> (
>   SELECT
>   ADD_MONTHS(CAST('01-JAN-'||(EXTRACT(year FROM SYSDATE)-1) AS DATE), ROWNUM-1) AS month_start,
>   LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(CAST('01-JAN-'||(EXTRACT(year FROM SYSDATE)-1) AS DATE), ROWNUM-1)) AS month_end
>   FROM DUAL
>   CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 12
> )
> , PERCENTS AS
> (
>  SELECT t.*
>  , EXTRACT(year from m.month_start) as "year"
>  , TO_CHAR(m.month_start,'MON') as "month"
>  , ROUND(100*((case when t.Res_End_Date < m.month_end then t.Res_End_Date else m.month_end end)
>   - (case when t.Res_Start_Date > m.month_start then t.Res_Start_Date else m.month_start end)
>   + 1)/(m.month_end-m.month_start+1)) as perc
>  FROM MONTHS m
>  JOIN YourTable t
>    ON t.Res_Start_Date <= m.month_end
>   AND (t.Res_End_Date IS NULL OR t.Res_End_Date >= m.month_start)
> )
> SELECT *
> FROM PERCENTS
> PIVOT (SUM(perc) FOR "month" IN ('JAN' JAN,'FEB' FEB,'MAR' MAR,'APR' APR,'MAY' MAY,'JUN' JUN,'JUL' JUL,'AUG' AUG,'SEP' SEP,'OCT' OCT,'NOV' NOV,'DEC' DEC)) pvt
> ORDER BY Team_Name DESC, Res_Name ASC
> ```
>
> ```
> TEAM_NAME | RES_NAME       | RES_START_DATE | RES_END_DATE | year |  JAN |  FEB |  MAR |  APR |  MAY |  JUN |  JUL |  AUG |  SEP |  OCT |  NOV |  DEC
> :-------- | :------------- | :------------- | :----------- | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---:
> Swoosh    | Bob Jones      | 01-JAN-19      | null         | 2019 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100
> Swoosh    | Mary Johnson   | 05-MAY-19      | null         | 2019 | null | null | null | null |   87 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100
> Marvel    | Bill Bobberson | 29-OCT-19      | 31-DEC-19    | 2019 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |   10 |  100 |  100
> Marvel    | David James    | 04-APR-19      | 28-APR-19    | 2019 | null | null | null |   83 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null
> Marvel    | John Smith     | 01-MAY-19      | 01-OCT-19    | 2019 | null | null | null | null |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |  100 |    3 | null | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=042b35ee001449dd43890e37aaa32b61)*

Comment: Pivoting `sum(perc)` would perhaps be better, assuming the same person may appear in the table twice for the same month. For example, someone may be on team `Marvel` from Jan. 1 to May 10 and then again (different row in the table!) from May 25 to November 30. But otherwise, this is likely the best solution.

Comment: @mathguy That's a good point. I never even considered that someone can rejoin the same team in the same month. Well, it's an easy fix for the OP if he reads your advice.

Comment: On second thought.  It would only matter if Res_Start_Date & Res_End_Date aren't needed in the final result.  Since the pivot groups by all fields that aren't used in the pivot declaration.  And if then someone worked 2 ranges in the same month, it would also show 2 records in the result.

Comment: True. That is a good question to throw back to the OP (who should, then, throw it back to his business users, instead of making up his own answer).